# Changing document path using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, path, alias

I have been given a folder in a subdomain to host my files.
https://sub.domain.com/folder

However the HTML files were all written referencing to root path (i.e. href="/css/style.css", etc.) which breaks everything.

Is there a way to htaccess and rewrite engine so that the codes will work with the root path set as /folder/ as root instead of /?

Comment: That might be possible, but it would create conflicts with any other content published under the same host name. Instead of trying to handle the symptom you should fix the cause: markup references should use relative paths which makes content deployable to different locations.

Comment: I would but I have inherited this bunch of compiled Vue codes from a 3rd party developer that is no longer available at my disposable.

Tried searching and replacing all to reference to relative path but there is still breakage somewhere.